# Word userform - only allowing to add data to bookmark once

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I do have a userform in word which populates predefined bookmarks with values. I use following code to write the text to the bookmark:

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()

Dim Text1 As Range
Set Text1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Text1").Range
Text1.Text = Me.ComboBox1.Value
```

When I hit the OK Button again, the text is added to the bookmark (and this can be done over and over again). This should not be possible. How can this be solved?

Comment: Have any of the proposed suggestions helped?

Answer (score 0):

If the bookmark should only be written to once, I'd remove the bookmark when writing to it the first time. If the code runs again, this would cause an error, so check for the existence of the bookmark, first.

For example

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()

Dim Text1 As Range
Dim doc As Document
Dim bkm As Bookmark
Dim bkmName As String

Set doc = ActiveDocument
bkmName = "Text1"
If doc.Bookmarks.exists(bkmName) Then
    Set bkm = doc.Bookmarks(bkmName)
    Set Text1 = bkm.Range
    Text1.Text = "test" ' Me.ComboBox1.value
    bkm.Delete
Else
    Debug.Print "The bookmark has been removed."
End If
End Sub
```

Note that this approach assumes that the bookmark type is an "I-beam" type of bookmark: it marks a position in the document and contains no content.

If "bracket" bookmarks are used (the bookmark surrounds/contains at least one character) then the assigning text to the bookmark automatically deletes the bookmark. In that case, the line `bkm.Delete` is not required.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, you would end an OK button sub with a command to close the userform, which discourages a second click:

```
  Unload UserForm1
```

But if you want to make it impossible to add the text a second time, you would add a check of the existing text in the bookmark:

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()
  Dim Text1 As Range
  Set Text1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Text1").Range
  If Text1.Text <> Me.ComboBox1.value Then
    Text1.Text = Me.ComboBox1.value
  Else
    MsgBox "That text has already been entered."
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Given the context of the problem description, the bookmark is an "I-beam" type and contains no content. So the check described above would not work.